# JavaScript - conditional throwing an uncaught syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I am currently working on a challenge to convert any amount of arbitrary numbers entered into the function below as a currency (expressed by a string where every three characters are separated by a comma). All was okay until I realized that if the length of the number entered was 4, then the comma would need to be placed as 1,234 rather than 123,4. 
It seems the function has spiralled out of control a little when I wrapped the initial if statement around my for loop. (1) I keep getting thrown an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else' in the console. (2) I thought it may be due trying to place an if/else around the for/if/else. Any light shed on my error would be much appreciated. Charlie

```
function toCurrency(price){


      var newStrng = price.toString().split("");

      var stringCh = [];

      if(newStrng.length===4){ 

          console.log("gotcha");
          stringCh = newStrng.splice(1,0,",");
          return stringCh;

        } else {

        for(var i = 0; i < newStrng.length; i++) {
          if(i %3 === 0 && i !== 0){

              stringCh.push(",");
              stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);

          }  
              } else {

                  stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);
              } 
        }

        var finallyDone = stringCh.join("");
        return finallyDone;

    }//EO function
```

Comment: Well, there is no `for { } else { }` statement in js :-) Always indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement in the following block

```
for(var i = 0; i < newStrng.length; i++) {
      if(i %3 === 0 && i !== 0){

          stringCh.push(",");
          stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);

      }  
          } else {

              stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);
          } 
    }
```

has an extra `}`, right before the `else`. Take it out and you should no long receive the syntax error.

You can make it easier to spot mistakes like this in the future by ensuring your code is properly indented so you can see which brackets are associated with which blocks.  Though I appreciate it could be reasonably indented in the source code and may not have copied across to SO perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `}` in the wrong place inside the `for` loop, that need to be moved after the `else` block.  As it is, the `if` statement is located in the `for` loop, but the `else` block is located outside of the loop, which is not valid syntax.

```
function toCurrency(price){
    var newStrng = price.toString().split("");
    var stringCh = [];

    if(newStrng.length===4){ 
        console.log("gotcha");
        stringCh = newStrng.splice(1,0,",");
        return stringCh;
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < newStrng.length; i++) {
            if(i %3 === 0 && i !== 0){
                stringCh.push(",");
                stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);
            } else {
                stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);
            }
        } 
    }

    var finallyDone = stringCh.join("");
    return finallyDone;

}//EO function
```

Answer (score 0):

remove } after,

```
stringCh.push(newStrng[i]);
```